# How to animate an object along a curve with the Z-axis of the object fixed?

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms

I am trying to move a cable car along the cable. ...up and down (!) the hill and around the pulley. This means the cable car object must move its x- and y-axis along the curve, while its z axis remains fixed (because its always hangs straight).

The "z-up twist" method doesn't work because like that x and y are also fixed.

With "follow curve" the z-axis moves according to the curve.

Comment: do you want that? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0585.gif if not, please add a link to an animation/video how it should look like. thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Surely someone here would like to help you, but with the information you provide here, I'm afraid that will not be possible. Please supplement your question with a detailed description of the problem, including images and other details. It might also be helpful if you share the blend file or at least provide a usable starting point. Otherwise, this question would be closed shortly. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: thank you very much chris! yes that is almost what i wanted, except that the cabin also should turn around when the "cable" is turning around the pulley (at the top and the bottom). best regards
christian

Comment: Add a Limit Rotation constraint after the Follow Path, and enable it for X and Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Illustration at the bottom, the red block has a *Follow Path* constraint on the yellow curve (left, below). The blue carriage-object is bound to the red block with a *Child Of* constraint, without including rotation in the axis across the slope (right, below).

[image]

The result is the carriage inheriting all the transforms of the block, except the tilt:

[image]

Unlike a *Limit Rotation* constraint, this method leaves you free to manually animate a bit of swing or wobble on the carriage, if you like.